# cannot run web applications on myeclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web

I used to program with netbeans, and recently changed into myeclipse.

but when I try to run any web applications on it. It shows this:

```
<terminated>myeclipseTomcatServer [Remote Java Application] 
<terminated, exit value:         1>C:\Users\chao's\MyEclipse\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.6.0.013\bin\javaw.exe (Oct 24, 2013 6:47:15 PM)
```

and the console shows this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 10\/metadata\/me_tcat\temp -Djava/library/path=C:\Users\chaos\MyEclipse\Common\binary\com/sun/java/jdk/win32/x86_64_1/6/0/013\bin;C:\Users\chaos\MyEclipse\Common\plugins\com/genuitec/eclipse/easie/tomcat/myeclipse_9/0/0/me201211011550\tomcat\bin -Dsun/io/useCanonCaches=false
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 10\.metadata\.me_tcat\temp -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\chaos\MyEclipse\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.6.0.013\bin;C:\Users\chaos\MyEclipse\Common\plugins\com.genuitec.eclipse.easie.tomcat.myeclipse_9.0.0.me201211011550\tomcat\bin -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Exception in thread "main"
```

I've tried my best to search for the solutions. but nothing works. It says that it could be cause by the java and JRE edition. I saw that all the edition in eclipse is 1.6.x. but my PC only have java 1.7 installed. Is that the main problem? How could I fix it?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 10\/metadata\/me_tcat\temp ` what is being passed as command line argument to tomcat ?

Comment: I just hit the run button in myeclipse. I am new to this. not sure about if there was any arguments passed.

Comment: goto run configuration, check classpath tab, check jre version (change it to jdk) it might give you hint

Answer (score 0):

As Jigar Joshi suggested, it looks like a server configuration error. If you open the server configuration (for example, by right clicking on the server, in the Servers view, and selecting "Configure Server Connector") and then go to the JDK page (open the MyEclipse Tomcat 6 item on the tree view, to get to the JDK page). From your error, you will probably see something like

```
10\/metadata\/me_tcat\temp -Djava/library/path=C:\Users\chaos\MyEclipse\Common\binary\com/sun/java/jdk/win32/x86_64_1/6/0/013\bin;C:\Users\chaos\MyEclipse\Common\plugins\com/genuitec/eclipse/easie/tomcat/myeclipse_9/0/0/me201211011550\tomcat\bin -Dsun/io/useCanonCaches=false
```

in the Optional Java VM Arguments text box. You shouldn't need any arguments here, so just delete the lot. If you do need arguments, make sure they are valid Java VM arguments ("10/metadata/me_tcat\temp" isn't a valid argument).

I'm surprised you have MyEclipse 9, if you've just switched from Netbeans. The latest release, available from the MyEclipseIDE web site, has many fixes and feature changes since release 9, so it would be worth installing that. The latest release also supports Java 7, so you'll be able to fully use your Java 7 JDK. To use external JDKs (MyEclipse comes with the 1.6 JDK) use standard eclipse features to add your own JRE (actually JDK), via the Java preferences.